# Python HTMLParser cannot parse complex custom tag attribute

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, custom-tags

I'm trying to use HTMLParser to parse the following HTML tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="movingEventItemId" value="<dt:value property="movingEventItemId" javaScriptSafe="1"/>"/>
```

When I get the individual attributes, I would expect it to return the following:

type - hidden

name - movingEventItemId

value - < dt:value property="movingEventItemId" javaScriptSafe="1" />

But value comes back as - < dt:value property=" javascriptsafe="1"/>

Python code:

```
 quote = '[\\\'\\"]'

 class HiddenInputParser(HTMLParser):
   def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
    if tag == 'input':
        id = self.findAttr('id', attrs)
        name = self.findAttr('name', attrs)
        if not name and not id:
            print('no name or id     ' + self.get_starttag_text())
        elif id is not None and name is not None and id != name:
            print('id != name    ' + self.get_starttag_text())
        else:
            id = (id if id else name)
            output = '<input type="hidden" id="' + id + '" name="' + id + '" '
            for attr in attrs:
                key = attr[0]
                if attr[1] and key != 'id' and key != 'name' and key != 'type':
                    matcher = re.search( key + '\\s*=\\s*(' + quote + ')', self.get_starttag_text(), re.IGNORECASE)
                    quote2 = matcher.group(1)
                    value = quote2 + attr[1] + quote2
                    output += ' ' + key + '=' + value
            output += '/>'
            print ( output )
    else:
        print ( self.get_starttag_text() )

    def findAttr(self, id, attrs):
      for attr in attrs:
          if attr[0] == id:
              return attr[1]


def fixHiddenInputs():
   inputParser = HiddenInputParser()
   files = []
   for extension in extensions:
      for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):
         for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, extension):
            for line in fileinput.input(os.path.join(root, filename), inplace=1):
                line = line.rstrip()
                if ( re.search( '<input.*type=' + quote + 'hidden' + quote,  line ) ):
                    inputParser.feed(line)
                else:
                    print( line)

def convertHiddenInputs():
   pass

convertHiddenInputs()
fixHiddenInputs()
```

The code is to add id to an input tag given the value of the name attribute. The final result should look like:

```
<input type="hidden" id="displayOptions" name="displayOptions" value="<dt:value property="movingEventItemId" javaScriptSafe="1"/>"/>
```

And this is what I'm getting:

```
<input type="hidden" id="displayOptions" name="displayOptions"  value="<dt:value property=" javascriptsafe="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the `id` for the tag there is no need parse the whole line and get every attribute. The better solution to your problem would just be to add the `id` to the element despite the rest of the attributes. If you need the `id` to be the same as the `name`, it looks like you are already getting the `name` attribute just fine. Just use the `name` you got and append `id="NAME_VALUE"` before or after it.

Cheers!